# How to combine rows and take highs and lows from those rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to generate a 5M OHLC chart (Open, High, Low, Close). I'm currently reading in data by the minute, but I want to make a 5 minute data chart as well which I can do pretty easy by simply doing

```
SELECT * FROM intraday_data.intraday WHERE intraday.id mod 5 = 0;
```

However, this doesn't accurately represent the data because for the OHLC chart to be accurate it would need to also have the open from the very first row and close from the very last row, and it would have to have the highest high from all 5 and the lower low from all 5 if that makes sense, I would also like to implement where it is able to add up all of the volumes.
[Here is the current schema:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx2e5.png)

As you can see the open in highlighted would need to be pulled out in the final row, the highlighted value in the 5th row which is the highest high as well as the remaining rows and the total volume, so essentially after running the function the row presented should be:

```
id 5: open 4402.75: high 4403: low 4402.5: volume : 12+24+37+32+29
```

Obviously, I would need to iterate over all of the rows and return every 5th row with the data combined from the last 5 rows,

Current Updated Query:

```
select open_close_t.cross_id,open_close_t.open_val,open_close_t.close_val,high_low_t.high,high_low_t.low,high_low_t.total_volume from (
    select open_close.max_id as cross_id,open_t.open as open_val,close_t.close as close_val from 
        (select max(id) as max_id,min(id) as min_id from intraday group by FLOOR(id/5)) as open_close
        inner join intraday as open_t on (open_t.id=open_close.min_id)
        inner join intraday as close_t on (close_t.id=open_close.min_id)
) as open_close_t
left join (
    select max(id) as cross_id,max(high_val) as high,min(low_val) as low,sum(volume) as total_volume 
        from (select id,GREATEST(open,high,low,close) as high_val,GREATEST(open,high,low,close) as low_val,volume from intraday_data.intraday) as _t
    group by FLOOR(id/5)
) as high_low_t on (open_close_t.cross_id=high_low_t.cross_id)
```

[Current Updated Results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL0Gg.png)

Comment: look up `GROUP BY`. Something like `GROUP BY FLOOR(id/5)`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Thank you but i dont believe this correctly iterates the previous rows as I need, it currently just gives me every 5 rows but does not add up the volume or provide the highest high or lowest low of the last 5.

Comment: you need to combine with SUM/MAX/MIN and other grouping functions

Answer (score 0):

we can seperate this question with two main query.

1. get the the open and close value

   - get max and min id of every 5th row
   - use that max_id and min id to get close and open value
2. get highest and lowest value

   - first we need get max and min cross open,high,low,close per row
   - group by 5th rows the previous generated and get highest and lowest values
3. join two previous generated table by max_id(cross_id in the sql) of each 5th rows

```sql
select open_close_t.cross_id,open_close_t.open_val,open_close_t.close_val,high_low_t.high,high_low_t.low,high_low_t.total_volume from (
    select open_close.max_id as cross_id,open_t.open as open_val,close_t.close as close_val from 
        (select max(id) as max_id,min(id) as min_id from intraday group by CEILING(id/5)) as open_close
        inner join intraday as open_t on (open_t.id=open_close.min_id)
        inner join intraday as close_t on (close_t.id=open_close.max_id)
) as open_close_t
left join (
    select max(id) as cross_id,max(high_val) as high,min(low_val) as low,sum(volume) as total_volume 
        from (select id,greatest(open,high,low,close) as high_val,least(open,high,low,close) as low_val,volume from intraday) as _t
    group by CEILING(id/5)
) as high_low_t on (open_close_t.cross_id=high_low_t.cross_id)
```

- fix every 4 instead every 5 bug,because I should use ceiling not floor
- the open_close temp table join problem from `close_t.id=open_close.min_id` to `close_t.id=open_close.max_id`
- the lowest value using `least` not `greatest`

I made a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kLtLPZgrfLQcHKwdY9gPLJ/0) example,if has further problem we can test on db-fiddle

Comment: So i implemented this and I think we are on the right track, I had to make some changes as in changing max to greatest as the syntax was bugging out, it seems the volume is working as it should be the open high low and close are not, I attached the results I am getting, I will also continue debugging this but wanted to let you know i was hvaving issues with it. Also I noticed that it is doing every 4 instead of every 5, which may be an issue.

Comment: This should also be u sing `least` instead of `greatest` when finding the LOW, since, you know, it should be the low

Comment: @maddiep123 sorry for does not test the sql.I had update my answer with test,hope can help you